# Visual Studio Load Test - What table is each test content length stored in

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I am trying to pull load test results out of SQL to generate custom reports.

On my agent machine's SQL Server I see the database structure:

```
LoadTest2010  
  -> Tables 
     ->dbo.LoadTestBrowsers   
     ->dbo.LoadTestCase    
     ...tables...
     ->dbo.WebLoadTestTransaction
```

For example I can find  the average page response time of each test in the [dbo.LoadTestPageSummaryData], however I cannot find the average content length of the test run (accessible on the summary page when viewing the results in VS) or of each of the individual tests in the load test. Am I overlooking a table?

Comment: What research have you done on finding the database content? What part of the published details do you not understand?

Comment: I just see a description of tables here (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/slumley/2010/02/12/description-of-tables-and-columns-in-vs-2010-load-test-database/) but I also see results not avaialble in SQL stored directly in the resulting TRX file generated at the end of a load test. Specifically looking for the average content length that I see in the test results summary.

Answer (score 0):

The summary information exists not in the LoadTest2010 tables but in the Views. Specifically [LoadTestComputedCounterSummary].